# Apply meta-magic on Magic surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, metamagic, wild-magic

Is it possible to apply careful spell on a magic surge for a example a cast 3rd level fireball centred on yourself, can you utilize careful spell in this case to save yourself and your allies?